# C "Error: Expecter expression before 'List'"

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, linked-list

I seem to get an error when I try to call a function.

My goal is to ask the user for some data and then "save it" in a linked list.

This is my header file:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

/*Protótipos*/

/* VARIÁVEIS GLOBAIS */
extern int sala_temporario , horas_inicio_temporario , minutos_inicio_temporario , horas_fim_temporario , minutos_fim_temporario;
extern char primeiro_nome_temporario[20] , ultimo_nome_temporario[20];
extern int sala , horas_inicio , horas_fim;
extern char primeiro_nome[20] , ultimo_nome[20];
/********************/

typedef struct lnode *List;

typedef struct lnode
{
    int sala, horas_inicio , minutos_inicio , horas_fim , minutos_fim;
    char primeiro_nome[20] , ultimo_nome[20];
    List next;
} List_node;



/*void procura_lista (List lista, ITEM_TYPE chave, List *ant, List *actual);*/

List cria_lista (void);
void fazer_reserva(int sala_temporario,int horas_inicio_temporario,int minutos_inicio_temporario,int horas_fim_temporario,int minutos_fim_temporario,char *primeiro_nome_temporario,char *ultimo_nome_temporario);
void Insere_Lista (List lista, int sala , int horas_inicio , int horas_fim , char *primeiro_nome , char *ultimo_nome);
```

Here is where I ask the user to input the data I want to  put on the list:

```
void fazer_reserva(int sala_temporario,int horas_inicio_temporario,int minutos_inicio_temporario,int horas_fim_temporario,int minutos_fim_temporario,char *primeiro_nome_temporario,char *ultimo_nome_temporario)
{


    printf("Insira o seu primeiro nome: ");
    scanf("%s", primeiro_nome_temporario);

    printf("Insira o seu ultimo nome: ");
    scanf("%s", ultimo_nome_temporario);

    printf("Insira o numero da sala que quer reservar: ");
    scanf("%d", &sala_temporario);

    printf("Horas de inicio de reserva (HH:MM): ");
    scanf("%2d:%2d", &horas_inicio_temporario , &minutos_inicio_temporario);

    printf("Horas de fim de reserva (HH:MM): ");
    scanf("%2d:%2d", &horas_fim_temporario , &minutos_fim_temporario);

    Insere_Lista (List lista, sala_temporario , horas_inicio_temporario, minutos_inicio_temporario , horas_fim_temporario , minutos_fim_temporario , primeiro_nome , ultimo_nome);

}
```

This is the part of the program where I get the error:

```
Insere_Lista (List lista, sala_temporario , horas_inicio_temporario, minutos_inicio_temporario , horas_fim_temporario , minutos_fim_temporario , primeiro_nome , ultimo_nome);
```

And this is how insert the data in the list:

```
void Insere_Lista (List lista, int sala , int horas_inicio , int minutos_inicio, int horas_fim , int minutos_fim , char *primeiro_nome , char *ultimo_nome)
{

    List no;
    no = (List) malloc (sizeof (List_node));
    if (no != NULL) {
        no-> primeiro_nome = primeiro_nome;
        no-> ultimo_nome = ultimo_nome;
        no-> sala = sala_temporario;
        no-> horas_inicio = horas_inicio;
        no-> minutos_inicio = minutos_inicio;
        no-> horas_fim = horas_fim;
        no-> minutos_fim = minutos_fim;



}
```

Sorry for the "newbie" mistakes, I hope you'll help me improve.
Thank you.

Comment: Just remove "`List`" from the line that causes the error...

Comment: read your first compiler error carefully. It will tell you the line of code at which the error is detected. It sounds like you have incorrect syntax before that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line has a syntax error:

```
Insere_Lista (List lista, sala_temporario , horas_inicio_temporario, minutos_inicio_temporario , horas_fim_temporario , minutos_fim_temporario , primeiro_nome , ultimo_nome);
```

You do not put type names before arguments when calling a function, only when declaring or defining the function. So you should not have `List` before `lista`.

Another problem is that you haven't declared the variable `lista`. Maybe you thought that doing it this way would declare the variable at the same time as calling the function (like you can declare a variable in `for (int i = 0; ...)`). That doesn't work, so you need to declare the variable before calling the function. So it should be:

```
List lista;
Insere_Lista (lista, sala_temporario , horas_inicio_temporario, minutos_inicio_temporario , horas_fim_temporario , minutos_fim_temporario , primeiro_nome , ultimo_nome);
```

I'm not sure why this argument is even needed. It matches the `aux` parameter in the `Insere_Lista()` function, but that parameter is never used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will implement the changes tomorrow and reply with some feedback. The "aux" parameter was incorrect, it was supposed to be "lista". Edited